# Delegate context

Tags: solidity, web3js

Using web3js i call a function in Contract A, in this contract i need to call function from Contract B but in context of address msg.sender form Contract A not an address of Contract A. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want msg.sender for contract B's function to be the caller of contract A?

If yes, then in contract B's function define an extra parameter for address and from contract A's function, when you call B's function send msg.sender as the newly defined parameter.

```
contract B {
   function myFuncB(address address) constant returns(address) {
        return address;
        // here you can use this address, as per your usecase.
   }    
}


import "./B.sol";
contract A {
   function myFuncA() {
    var obj = new B(msg.sender);
    obj.myFuncB();
   }    
}
```

Hope this helps.